# Zero and the definition of Complex exponents

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function

In the book ["Complex variables and applications" (pg 101)](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edturaev/churchill1.pdf), the following is written:

> When $z\not= 0$ and the exponent c is any complex number, the function $z^c$ is defined by the means of the equation
> $$z^c=e^{c\log z}$$

This definition implies that $0^{a},\forall a \in \Bbb C$ is undefined.

Does this mean that expressions like $0^3,0^{i}$ which are clearly $0$, are in fact undefined? How can this be?

EDIT 2:
I got to know $0^i$ is undefined.

Comment: What about $0^{-1}$?

Comment: They explicitly say that this definition is for $z\ne0$.

Comment: Why should $0^i$ be "clearly" $0$ ?

Comment: $0^i$ is undefined

Comment: $0^a$ fails immediately for _any_ negative $a$, not just $-1$. I've extended my answer with some relevant other definitions.

Comment: @Troposphere when $a$ is any other negative number, we run into the "problem" of $0^a$, the expression that itself is under question and so I decided to omit it. I added further comment for your answer. I appreciate your time.

Comment: The word undefined does not even appear on page 101 at all. The definition does not imply that anything is "undefined".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that *that* particular definition doesn't define $0^3$.

There are other definitions that do. It generally works out such that when two of the definitions both assign a value to $a^b$, they agree which value it is -- so it doesn't create much practical confusion consider them to be complementary partial definitions of a single "exponentiation" concept.

(However, this correspondence does start to creak a bit at the seams if we use $z^w = e^{w\log z}$ on negative $z$, where using the principal value for $\log z$ leads to a different result for, say, $(-8)^{1/3}$ than the usual all-real cube root does).

I'm not aware of any commonly used definition that attempts to assign a value to $0^w$ when $w\in \mathbb C\setminus[0,\infty)$. In contrast to $0^3$, the expression $0^i$ is not generally meaningful.

---

In response to the edited question, here is a (not exhaustive) list of some important complementary defintions for exponentiation:

1. A recursive definition for $a^n$ when $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $a$ is any element of a *monoid* whose composition is notated multiplicatively -- such as $(\mathbb C,{\times})$: $$ a^0 = 1 \qquad\qquad a^{n+1} = a^na $$
2. An extension of the above to $n\in\mathbb Z$ when $a$ is any element of a multiplicatively notated *group* -- such as $(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},{\times})$: $$ a^{-n} = \text{the inverse of }a^n \quad\text{when }n>0 $$ which in particular justifies the standard notation $a^{-1}$ for multiplicative inverses.
3. Building on the above, an extension to $a^b$ where $b\in\mathbb Q$ and $a$ is an element of a group where $x\mapsto x^q$ is a bijection -- such as $(\mathbb R_{>0},{\times})$, or $(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\},{\times})$ if $q$ is odd: $$ a^{p/q}=x \iff x^q = a^p $$
4. When the base is the particular real number $e$, and $A$ is an element of any topological unital $\mathbb R$-algebra (which in particular might be $\mathbb C$) such that the series on the right converges: $$ e^A = 1 + A + \frac{A^2}2 + \cdots + \frac{A^n}{n!} + \cdots $$

Note that before $z^w = e^{w\log z}$ can define *anything*, you need to already have something much like definition (4), and that itself builds on definition (1).

And even then, $e^{w\log z}$ is really the "odd one out" among the definitions, in that it really wants to be multivalued -- so the best we can say about compatibility is that if one of the other definitions define $z^w$ and $z\ne 0$, then the outcome of that other definition will be *among* the possible values of $e^{b\log a}$.

Comment: (+1) for first sentence. Regarding all this, I would add that if we're going really nitpick the wording, then note that the author says "the function $z^c$", which doesn't necessarily imply that specific arithmetic evaluations involving complex numbers are not defined (any more than defining the function $f(x) = x + 2$ for $x > 0$ implies that $-3 + 2$ is not defined), although I suspect the author doesn't intend this reading.

Comment: I understand that we can use def(3)  to prove something like $0^3=0$, or some other rational powers, but I think in order to truly cover the tracks it's best to go ahead and define $0^{a}=0$, wherever applicable. This seems to solve all problems.

Comment: @GreasyToothBee: No, because there's a huge swaths of applications (e.g. polynomials, their various generalizations, the binomial theorem, etc.) that become full of pesky special cases if we decide to define $0^0$ to be anything else than $1$.

Comment: @GreasyToothBee: Also the completely fundamental definition (1) is enough to fix $0^3=0$.

Comment: @Troposphere we don't have to define $0^0$ to be anything. I just want to define it to be zero wherever applicable. It is true that $0^3=0$ can be derived from def(1), but my point about rational powers still stands.

Comment: @GreasyToothBee: So what do you think of as "applicable" here? It would be a sad loss if we couldn't rely on $a^ba^{-b}$ being $1$ whenever it's defined at all -- how would you resolve that for $a=0$, $b=i$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127093/discussion-between-greasytoothbee-and-troposphere).

Comment: So basically $0^{a}=0; a\in \Bbb R^{+}$ is sufficient

Comment: (Outcome of chat discussion: It turns out we both agree that $0^a$ should be $0$ when $a$ is a positive real, even though none of the definitions I chose to quote in the answer handles that case).

Comment: Note $0^i$ is indeterminate, at best.  For example, consider $a^i$ with $a \to 0^+$.  Does not converge.